# What are GlassFish 3.1.x domain initializers?

Tags: glassfish-3

I am seeing this log message when using the create-domain command with GlassFish 3.1.1

```
No domain initializers found, bypassing customization step
```

What can be accomplished with domain initializers? Is there any documentation?

Examples of create-domain usages with logging output is shown here,

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2433/create-domain-1.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reference manual reports:

> If domain customizers are found in JAR files in the as-install/modules
>   directory when the create-domain subcommand is run, the customizers
>   are processed. A domain customizer is a class that implements the
>   DomainInitializer interface.

I did found no documentation about customization but based on the source I can figure out that domain initializers are used to customize domain.xml during domain creation.

```
package org.glassfish.api.admin.config;

import org.jvnet.hk2.annotations.Contract;
import org.glassfish.api.admin.config.Container;

/**
 * Marker interface to mark inhabitants that require some minimal initial 
 * configuration to be inserted into a newly create domain's domain.xml
 *
 * @author Nandini Ektare
 */
@Contract
public interface DomainInitializer {
    /**
     * The actual initial config that needs to be inserted into
     * the fresh domain.xml
     *
     * See {@link Attribute#value()} for how the default value is inferred.
     *
     */
    public <T extends Container> T getInitialConfig(DomainContext initialCtx);
}
```

You can find source [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish.common/glassfish-api/3.1/org/glassfish/api/admin/config/DomainInitializer.java).

the `getInitialConfig` method returns a `Container` instance. `Container` interface extends `org.jvnet.hk2.config.ConfigBeanProxy` interface that appears to be a proxy to `Dom` class:

```
/**
 * Marker interface that signifies that the interface
 * is meant to be used as a strongly-typed proxy to
 * {@link Dom}. 
 *
 * <p>
 * To obtain the Dom object, use {@link Dom#unwrap(ConfigBeanProxy)}.
 * This design allows the interfaces to be implemented by other code
 * outside DOM more easily.
 *
 * @author Kohsuke Kawaguchi
 * @see Dom#unwrap(ConfigBeanProxy)
 * @see DuckTyped
 * @see Element
 * @see Attribute
 */
public interface ConfigBeanProxy {
```

I figure out that [hk2](http://hk2.java.net/) is the key to understand how domain customization works.

I hope someone else can give you some more useful info.